# Useful velocity gadgets

Tags: java, velocity, template-engine

There are lots of interesting JSP tag libraries.

I wanted to know what good Velocity gadgets or libraries or resusable components are out there.

Please one per answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Velocity works mean that you more often than not do not need the equivalent of a JSP tag library.

For example jstl c:* tag libraries are covered by the Velocity built-in directives.  To do any of the fmt:* tag library functionality you simply add a Formatter object to the Velocity context and call methods on it.  e.g. `$datefmt.format($date)`

This means you can get a lot further without resorting to tag libraries.  For those common tasks that are complex enough to require some additional code there is alway the standard Velocity tools:

http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/

In particular:

http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic.html

Comment: Why disappointing? You have access to zillions of existing java helper libs without any extra work. What are you looking for?